# Virtual memory and MMU confusion in embedded systems

Tags: memory-management, embedded, microcontroller, mmu, cortex-a

Does it make sense, or can we benefit from having an MMU (Memory Management Unit) on a microcontroller if not running an Operating System of any sort?

Take for example the ARM Cortex A8 based chip used on the beaglebone board for example which includes an MMU. From my understanding, this provides the benefit that can allow us to run embedded Linux for example or some other OS.

My confusion is, is the MMU much use to us if we don't use an OS? From my understanding, virtual memory is a memory management technique that is provided by both hardware and software working together. Do we need the OS to continuously update and change the mapping of physical addresses to virtual addresses, or can this be done in just hardware? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the mmu can have a performance penalty as every transaction has to be looked up.  there is the equivalent of a small cache in the mmu if you keep hitting the same address space, but there is still extra time spent for every transaction.  The benefits are as Clifford described, the mmu allows you to control cachable ranges and other features of the bus/system that you cannot do any other way, if not using an operating system you can make the virtual address = physical to make life easier on yourself...

Comment: you can make it static if you are just using the mmu to control properties of your memory space.  the constant changing is when folks are mallocing and freeing and the os is loading and loading programs, etc.  single tasking you can just set it one time if you want, or can muck with it runtime, your design your choice.

Answer (score 3):

The MMU can assign attributes such as read-only, read-write, invalid and cacheability.  The latter is essential if using DMA transfers on a cache-enables system for example, and setting an address range invalid can ensure an exception if the application accesses non-existent memory.  It may also be used to block access to peripherals your application is not using - again to more likely generate an exception for an errant application.  Setting your ROM space read-only has a similar error trapping benefit.

These are perhaps not huge benefits, but if you have an MMU, you may as well use it, even if it is a largely static configuration.  The same benefits can be realised using the MPU on lower end Cortex-M parts for example - essentially would be using the MMU as an MPU.

This simple approach to MMU usage applied to OS-less and a relatively simple RTOS/IPC executive - many of which do not have comprehensive MMU support.

It would even be possible to implement a swap-file system without an OS, but if you need that large an address space your application will probably benefit from an OS, or you will be half way to building your own.

Comment: Thanks. regarding an MMU, the Page Table Entries must be entered by the software such as the OS? Or will the MMU have some default mapping from virtual addresses to physical addresses in hardware maybe if not explicitly set? Just a concept I still don't fully understand

Comment: @Engineer999 : Refer to the data sheet for your part. If you intend to manage the MMU yourself you will need to do that in any event.  on ARM Cortex-A8 the MMU is disabled on start-up - you configure it before enabling it.  Without it all memory is accessed through physical addresses and will be read/write.

Comment: We actually used the MMU with a simple RTOS (threadx) to support demand paging of code from a non-linear flash device.  It allowed us to execute a much larger modal program than our on chip SRAM (~256KB) would allow without having to do explicit swapping of code for each mode.    It also allowed us to have a system with SDRAM and use the on chip SRAM as an L2 cache.  In both cases, it required us to profile the code and manage locality of code so we could lock down 'hot' pages, but it worked well.